# What is an ideal pattern for supporting optionally asynchronous callbacks in ES6?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I find myself frequently doing the following. Is there a more succinct or idiomatic pattern for this?

```
function my_func(some_fn) {
  const promise = some_fn();

  if (promise) {
    promise.then(do_thing);
  } else {
    do_thing();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, don't create functions that sometimes return a promise and sometimes don't.  Just always return a promise.  If you have no async operation to do, then just `return Promise.resolve()` and the calling code is always consistent and simpler as they can just always use the returned promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the only problem specific aspect of your code is the `do_thing` function. Just pass that in:

```
function generalized_hof(some_fn, callback) {
  const promise = some_fn();

  if (promise) {
    promise.then(callback);
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}
```

Then just use it like:

```
generalized_hof(
    /* Potentially promise generating function */, 
    /* Callback function */)
```

Obviously `generalized_hof` is an awful name. I'm not entirely sure what you'd call this function though.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function my_func(some_fn) {
  await some_fn();  
  do_thing();
}
```

... perhaps with try catch ...

```
async function my_func(some_fn) {
  try {
      await some_fn();
  } catch (err) { /* handle error */ }
  do_thing();
}
```

Comment: OP wants to do that in ES6, `async/await` is ES7 feature.

Comment: Perhaps use babel to transpile to es6..? Async/Await is worth the effort, especially with try/catch as it lets you handle errors from original calling context instead of each promise chain having to manage it's own error handling.

Comment: Yeah but this answer is not about transpiling with a thrid party library

Comment: While this doesn't technically answer the question I asked, I appreciate this solution and it's probably the direction I'll go as babel is already in my toolchain. Looking at [await on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) it does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with:

```
function my_func(some_fn) {
  const promise = some_fn();
  promise ? promise.then(do_thing) : do_thing();
}
```

And to have a one-liner I'll go with:

```
function my_func(some_fn) {
  (some_fn = some_fn()) ? some_fn.then(do_thing) : do_thing();
}
```

The second one is a bit weird as assigning different types to the same variable is a bit hackish and to people used to typed languages is an aberration, but hey, that's one of JavaScript beautiful things, isn't it? (as long as you know what you are doing)

EDIT: If you are repeating this exact pattern a lot, [@Carcigenicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46757708/1525495) is the way to go.